# Add dynamic articles to localStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have got a problem with adding articles with images (as base64) into my localStorage.

```
 $('.img2ls').ready(function(event){
 var imageUrl = $(this).find('img[id=img]').attr('src');

var picture = convertImgToBase64(imageUrl, function(base64Img){
     console.log('image', base64Img);
 });
var copy = $('.text2ls').html();

var article = {
   "image": picture,
   "text": copy
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(article));

localStorage.setItem('articles', article);

event.preventDefault();
});
```

But there is an error and I cannot achieve my aim. The idea is to save content of all divs with class 'img2ls' into localStorage for retrieving it later.

Please amend my jsfiddle so I know what exactly I am doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/p86mu4at/2/

Really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You `convertImgToBase64` function does not return anything, hence the `picture` variable is `undefined`.

Comment: For some reasons it works with - console.log('image', base64Img);